# Typeahead-addresspicker - JS assist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker gem on a project and I really dislike how the placeholder text shows in the actual input field while I'm typing an address. How can I remove this?

Here's the app - [www.justbooked.com/beta](http://justbooked.com/beta)

As you begin typing an address you'll notice the address is displayed awkwardly in the input field, I'd like to just have the address options show in the dropdown below as I type and remove it from input field, until I select one.

Looking for a JS expert to share the best way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style to hide the address hint:

```
.tt-hint {
  display: none;
}
```

To prevent capitalization of the text in the suggestions, use the following style:

```
.tt-suggestion {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks @CodeWarrior been looking for a solution to this for quite some time! There's one other small petepeve I have, when you type the addresses below are all capitalized, how can we downcase them?

Comment: Updated my answer to address your capitalization issue.